# Minimizing the integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need help in the following question.

Let $$J(u)=\int_0^1\left[u_x^2+4\frac{u^2}{x^2}\right]xdx,$$ where $u(x)$ is a smooth function defined on $[0,1]$ satisfyig $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=1$. Which one of the following functions minimizes $J$?

$1.$ $u(x)=x^2$

$2.$ $u(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}x^2$

$3.$ $u(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$

$4.$ $u(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^2$

My attempt: given conditions $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=1$ are satisfied by only $1$st option, hence the answer.

Is my attempt right? I would appreciate if somebody can mention another approach to solve this question.

Comment: The question is strange, as you're right that only the first is even a valid option. So that's that. Without the condition for the boundaries, notice that $J(c\cdot u)=c^2\ J(u)$. Specifically if $j:=J(x^2)$ is some fixed postitive number, then $J(b\ x^2)=b^2\ j$ and so the function $b\ x^2$ with the smallest $b$ wins.

Comment: but then 1st option has the largest b among the given options.

Comment: As you pointed out already, the other options are invalid.